# How to pronounce eu in a latin word?

Tags: pronunciation, latin

How should I pronounce the latin name [*Sporosarcina pasteurii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporosarcina_pasteurii)? According to [Pronunciation of Biological Latin](http://capewest.ca/pron.html) : *"Latin biological names in English speech are usually pronounced with English letter sounds."* But I am not sure what is the letter sound of the `eu`, `ii`, and `sarcina`?

Comment: *Pasteur* is pronounced in the closest Anglophone approximation to that great French scientist’s name. I am unfamiliar with IPA, but something like “Past-tyur”. The Latin plural suffix `ii` is pronounced identically to *eye*. The *sarcina* is also straightforward: *sar-seen-uh* (or *-ah*). So altogether *Spor-o-sar-SEEN-uh Past-TYUR-eye*.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks! This sounds correct to me. I think the IPA symbol for the `yur`-sound is `ɜːr`?

Comment: You’re asking the wrong guy! Though I’m sure he Wikipedia article on *Pasteur* can give you the correct IPA for his name, though perhaps not the correct IPA for how an American (eg) might pronounce it. I’m still not convinced whether I’ve given you the right guidance on the final vowel in *sarcina*; my instinct is that anyone pronouncing it carefully would use an *a* sound, but in general discourse it would be *uh*, but this strongly depends on whether the daily register among biologists has rules for this. But I’ll tell you, e.g., *gorilla* is pronounced *gorill-uh*, not *-ah*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual English way to pronounce *eu* in a word from Latin is as "long u" (which in IPA can be any of /juː/, /uː/, /jɜː/, /ɜː/, /jʊ/, /ʊ/, /jə/, /ə/ depending on the context). For example, the first syllable of the word *neuter* is pronounced the same as the word *new*—as /njuː/, or /nuː/ in American English. But because *Pasteurii* is built on a non-Latin name, it is likely to be pronounced with the "nurse" vowel (IPA /ɜː/) instead, which loosely approximates the value of French /œ/. Compare the word *[Pasteurian/pasteurian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Pasteurian),* which Merriam-Webster says is pronounced "\ paˈstərēən \" = IPA /pæˈstɜːriən/.

The traditional pronunciation of word-final *-ii* in a word from Latin is /iaɪ/, but nowadays some people say /ii/ due to influence from the "restored" pronunciation of Latin.

*Sarcina* should be pronounced with stress on the third-to-last syllable, because the *i* was short in Latin according to [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=sarcina). If the *i* were long in Latin, the regular pronunciation in English would put the stress on the second-to-last syllable and give the *i* the quality of /aɪ/ (as in the word *vagina* or the place name *Carolina*). A word ending in *-ina* that is properly stressed the same way as *sarcina* is *machina* in the phrase *deus ex machina* (the OED indicates stress on the first syllable of *machina*).

Altogether, I would pronounce *Sporosarcina pasteurii* as /ˌspɔːroʊˈsɑːrsɪnə pæˈstɜːriaɪ/. The vowel in the second syllable of *Sporosarcina* could be reduced to /ə/, and in British English, the first syllable might be pronounced with /ɒr/ instead of /ɔːr/. The second syllable of *pasteurii* might perhaps be pronounced with the "CURE" vowel, as /pæˈstjʊər-/ (or in American English /pæˈstʊr-/ or /pæsˈtʃʊr-/). The last two syllables of *pasteurii* might be pronounced as /ii/ instead of as /iaɪ/. Of course, in a British English accent, there would be no *r* consonant after the *a* in *Sporosarcina* (/ˌspɔːrəʊˈsɑːsɪnə/ or /ˌspɒrəʊˈsɑːsɪnə/) and in an American English accent this syllable would be pronounced with an r-colored vowel (something like /ˌspɔ˞roʊˈsɑ˞sɪnə/ or /ˌspo˞roʊˈsɑ˞sɪnə/).